# Why is Polars streaming engine so slow?

Tags: python, dataframe, parquet, python-polars

I have a directory of parquet files and am looking to apply a function to all of them and take an average.

At first I thought that Polars would excel at this with LazyFrame and streaming functionality, but it seems a naive approach of looping through chunks of data and loading iteratively outperforms. Is there something wrong with my implementation that is causing this?

```
%%time
unique_years = (
    pl.scan_parquet(data_glob)
    .select(pl.col("time").dt.year().unique())
    .collect()
    .to_series()
    .to_list()
)

results = []
for year in tqdm(unique_years):
    results.append(
        pl.scan_parquet(data_glob)
        .filter(pl.col("time").dt.year()==year)
        .select(["time", "market", "close"])
        .sort("time")
        .with_columns(pl.col("close").log().diff().over("market").alias("log_returns"))
        .group_by("time")
        .agg(pl.col("log_returns").mean())
        .collect()
    )
CPU times: user 10min 10s, sys: 4min 44s, total: 14min 55s
Wall time: 2min 4s
```

```
%%time
df = (
    pl.scan_parquet(data_glob)
    .select(["time", "market", "close"])
    .sort("time")
    .with_columns(pl.col("close").log().diff().over("market").alias("log_returns"))
    .group_by("time")
    .agg(pl.col("log_returns").mean())
    .collect(streaming=True)
)
```

The first approach, which I assumed to be incorrect, finishes relatively quickly, whereas the second does not execute within any reasonable amount of time. It seems odd that the streaming engine is so inefficient that simple looping can outperform it.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example containing the underlying data asset? Currently, I suspect the latter code doesn't take the grouping by year into account preventing polars from optimizing as much as in the loop-solution.

Comment: Run each of them but replace collect with profile. (ie `profile()` and `profile(streaming=True)`). Find a way to shrink the problem (ie filter it for 2 or 3 years only) and only do those years in the top case so that your streaming example can finish with a profile. At a high level the answer is that streaming sacrifices speed for memory. If you want specifics, that's what profile is for.

Comment: This doesn't run on the streaming engine. Window functions are not supported streaming. And window functions are expensive. So maybe that's the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort`, `diff`, `over`, and `mean` functions are not supported by the streaming engine. Like @ritchie46 mentions, the window functions are the expensive functions here.

This [article](https://www.rhosignal.com/posts/streaming-operations-in-polars/) tests most of the functions in Polars and draws some conclusions about what the streaming engine can and cannot do. Note: these are done on a pair of floating point columns. Either way, if you look at the plan of your query, you will see which parts are not getting included in the streaming engine and go from there. You can use the `explain(streaming=True)` command to see what is run outside the `--- STREAMING` tags.